# Reading documents from a MongoDB collection and writing them locally using Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I am using MongoDB Scala driver trying to access a MongoDB collection and "download" the documents contained within to a JSON file. The number of documents in the collection is measured in 100Ks, but a similar task in python (downloading, creating a pd.DataFrame and storing as CSV) takes 10 minutes while trying to do it in spark-shell it takes over an hour easily. I sense I am doing something very wrong, but can't figure out what.

```
val documents = db.getCollection("collectionName").find().toFuture()

documents on Complete {
  case Success(docs) => {
    // without partitioning tasks would become too large - resulting in most docs being written as empty
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(docs, 1000)
    val ds = spark.read.json(rdd.map(_.toJson).toDS)
    ds.write.mode("overwrite").json("/path/to/data/data.json")
  }
  case Failure(e) => println("Error")
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: why don't you directly read as dataframe?  here is an example https://koiralo.com/2020/06/21/how-to-read-and-write-data-from-mongodb-with-spark3/

Comment: if you need spark to create the csv follow the instructions in https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/read-from-mongodb/